# How do I increase display by 120% of normal? Using Mac Air, Yosemite OS

Tags: macos, mac, zoom

In Windows one can right click, head over to display preferences and have the OS increase everything globally ... icons, fonts, etc ... by a certain factor.   It's really helpful for "old" eyes.   Is there an equivalent for Mac?   I have found zillions of places to tweak things piecemeal.  But am looking One place, One setting.   Am certain it exists, but as a Mac novice I have struggled.

Am using Mac Air; OS X Yosemite 10.10.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is the Zoom from Accessibility, instead of the annoying fullscreen mode you can do picture to picture that isn’t so annoying. To increase the everything you’ll have to change the resolution as @denisinla mentioned. That’s has the draw-back of not looking so good.

Otherwise you’ll have to do increase size app by app. Most apps now have zoom options, like in Safari it’s under View menu, in Mail it’s under Window; just search in the Help menu and it should show. To make the icons bigger right click any Finder window, and Show View Options. There you can set it as you like, and click Use as Defaults. The sidebar size can be increased in General Pref Pane. You can also increase the cursor size Accessibility -> Display. The Dock can be resized by dragging the Line next to trash up and down, or in the pref pane. Also apps have a convention of using ⌘+Plus and ⌘+Minus or with Shift and Alt for zooming. You can always try that.

So options are there but there isn’t a global one, except the Zoom feature from Accessibility.

Comment: Thx - seems there is no One Place, One Setting way to do and achieve results similar to the Windows feature.   Appreciate your advice, as well as the others on the thread.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
System Preferences -> Accessibility -> Zoom
```

More details [here](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18385?locale=en_US)

Comment: Thx - I had found that setting area earlier.   But i still cant figure out how to make everything bigger, all the time and keep it that way.   What am i missing?

Answer (score 1):

How about increasing your screen resolution by adjusting it in

```
System Preferences > Displays > Scaled > Adjust for Larger Text - More Space
```

Answer (score 0):

For permanent and full screen increase in fonts ect use System Preferences.

Select Display, now hold the "alt" key and click on scaled.

Here I would choose the 1024x640 and if it is to large choose next one.

Comment: Thx - I tried this.  Unfortunately some things became fuzzy.

Comment: Fuzzy but big :) or try next higher to see